# How to correlate a selection from a list of options with the associated command?

Tags: python

So basically, what I'm trying to do is to create a menu that allows me to modify the contents of a text file. It's supposed to look like this:
[Question 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IU6R.png)

I think I already know how to create the menu, as shown here:

```
print("User Management")
print("1.Add new record")
print("2.View all record")
print("3.Search record")
print("4.Exit")



option = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
if option == 1 :
```

The problem I have I have no idea how to correlate the options to the commands. For example, if I wanted to correlate this:

```
name = input("Please enter your name:")
email = input("Please enter your email address:")
f = open("user.txt","a")
f.write("\n"+name+","+email)
f.close()
print("Record added."))
```

to 1 so whenever I input 1 in the "Enter your choice" it allows me to add a name and email address to the text file, etc. Here's an example I can find:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyRiK.png)

I have been told that using the `if` and `elseif` functions allows me to do that, but I have no idea how. I'm quite new to Python, so forgive me if I seem ignorant. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Add image as code

Answer (score 0):

You're right in that using a conditional (the fancy technical term for `if`/`elseif`/`else`) is the way to do that. Assuming that the text you have included in your question is accurate, it's likely that you haven't indented the code that is meant to be in the `if` block.

Python uses indentation (that is, spaces or tabs) to indicate what code is within each control structure. So in your example, if you want to only execute the second block of text if `option == 1` you would want:

```
print("User Management")
print("1.Add new record")
print("2.View all record")
print("3.Search record")
print("4.Exit")

option = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
if option == 1 :
    name = input("Please enter your name:")
    email = input("Please enter your email address:")
    f = open("user.txt","a")
    f.write("\n"+name+","+email)
    f.close()
    print("Record added."))
```

For more on using `if` and other control flow, [see the tutorial here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Comment: first of for sth like this defining a function and then using dictionary to manage what user input does would be better, also I would suggest using `with` to open files

Comment: @Matiiss I mean sure, there a plenty of ways to improve the code example from the question, but that doesn't really answer the basic question of how to write an `if` statement. Best to start with the basics before introducing using `dict` for control flow (or `match` if you're running Python 3.10).